# First statement issued by SQL Server Agent sets quoted_identifier off

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

As I can see in SQL Server Profiler, the first statement issued by SQL Server Agent when it begins to execute a job step, is

```
select c.name, c.description 
from master.dbo.syscharsets c 
where c.id = convert(tinyint, databasepropertyex ( db_name() , 'sqlcharset'))  

set quoted_identifier off
```

In my job steps I always need `quoted_identifier` to be set to on.

How can I change this behavior?

Default connection setting for the server is set to On.

```
select @@version
```

Output:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (Intel X86) 
Sep 22 2011 00:28:06 
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 <X86> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a workaround could be adding a 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON' at the beginning of the job.

Comment: Yes, of cause, it's possible to add "set quoted_identifier on" at the begining of each step. But the question is - "is it possible to change this behavior of Sql Agent, or is it a bug, or my mistake?"